# Is it permissible to hire another freelancer to take over my client's work?

Tags: business, freelance

I'm a graphic design freelancer and I was asked to design a logo by a client. I designed the logo for my client but the client did not like any of my logos and asked me to design more. I have a feeling he won't like my designs again.

So, is it okay if I ask another freelancer from a different company to design a logo for my client? What can I do?

Comment: What does your contract say? Does your contract allow you to farm work out to subs?

Answer (score 3):

It's typical. Much of the industry works this way--whether it's agencies subbing out to freelancers or freelancers subbing out to other freelancers. When I hire a contractor do remodel my kitchen, I leave it up to them to decide which parts to sub out. All I care is that I'm dealing with one person and that one person is on the line for the project.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is normal as long as your client will be informed about that and/OR a freelancer/company will not have any further commercial rights for the product they've created (say, selling or adapting for another work). Also, questions about who showcase the work in the portfolio should also be solved.

But I would suggest you to not give up and try a few more variants, it's all about understanding what your client wants. At last even if you do something that feels bad for you and great for a client, it's just his position and taste because every person there has individual view on things, especially when it comes to design. Try to ask him more concrete questions, draw out more information (most liked examples of work, colors, styles, etc.). There may be very hard clients but usually if you do something based or similar to the example they like the work is going to be approved.

Comment: Can you expand what you mean by "[they] will not have any further commercial rights"? I don't understand what you're trying to say. As for showcasing the work, it would be immoral for the OP to claim the other person's design as their own